# Why is GetPaged() Executing two database calls?

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I'm a bit new to subsonic (i.e. evaluating 3.0.0.3) and have come across a strange behavior in GetPaged(int pageIndex, int pageSize).  When I execute the method it does **two** SQL calls.  Any ideas why ?

### Details

Lets say I have a "Cultures" table with 200 rows.  In my code I do something like ...

```
var sonicCollection = from c in RTE.Culture.GetPaged(1, 25)
                       select c;
```

Now, I would expect this executes a single query returning the first 25 entries in my cultures table. When I watch SQL profiler I see two queries run by.

First this--

```
SELECT [dbo].[Cultures].[cultureCode], [dbo].[Cultures].[cultureName]
FROM [dbo].[Cultures]
```

Then This--

```
SELECT *
FROM     (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    ORDER BY cultureID ASC) AS Row, 
    [dbo].[Cultures].[cultureCode], [dbo].[Cultures].[cultureName]
 FROM [dbo].[Cultures]
)
AS PagedResults
WHERE  Row >= 1 AND Row <= 25
```

I expect the 2nd query to roll by, as it is the one returning the 25 rows I politely requested of subsonic.   The first query, however, appears to return 200 rows (at least according to SQL profiler).

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in the code.  The code actually queries every record and then iterates over each one for the count.  I've created an issue in the github repo here:
https://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/issues/259

You can download the source, fix the issue and recompile pretty easily.  I've done this and its fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You just want to use RTE.Culture.GetPaged() - it runs the paged query for you.

Comment: Sorry, slip up on my part...  I changed the code to just :

     var colPaged = RTE.Culture.GetPaged(1, 20);

I'm still seeing the two query behavior.